# Pass data to AppDelegate from ViewController Mac OS

Tags: swift, macos

I have been attempting to pass data from a view controller to the AppDelegate file, and am having no luck. I want to access variable l in the view controller.
The code I have been using is as follows:

```
    let navController = window!.contentViewController as! NSWindowController

    let SettingsController = navController.contentViewController as! SettingsViewController

    var list = itemsController.l
```

Obviously this does not work and generates a runtime error. By the way I am using a

```
        var window: NSWindow?
```

Sorry if this did not make sense as English is not my first language.

Answer (score 0):

First, do you mean:

```
let itemsController = navController.contentViewController as! SettingsViewController
```

Second, if you are trying to access AppDelegate, you should called:

```
guard let appDelegate = NSApplication.shared.delegate as? AppDelegate else {
     return
}
```

to get the AppDelegate. Then you can get the window you are looking for by:

```
window = appDelegate.window
```

I think this is what you are looking for.